# Designing a website with several independent hierarchies

Tags: website-design, navigation, information-architecture, relations

I am designing a personal-academic website in which the material is organized in two ways:

- By type, e.g. "Publications", "Working papers", "Demos", etc.
- By topic, e.g. "Bible", "Algorithms", "Auctions" etc.
- By time (year).

Each topic, type and year can potentially go together, e.g. there are publications in each topic from several different years, working papers in each topic, etc.

What is a good way to organize such a website?

EDIT: The website is for several types of target audience:

- Workers from industry who may be interested in the research, use it in their work and maybe offer job opportunities.
- Researchers from academy who may be interested in the research, cite it in their papers and maybe offer collaborations.
- Academic personnel who may want to see the research record in order to consider academic position opportunities.

My goal is to make it easy for visitors to find the piece of work that is most interesting to them.

Comment: Who is the target audience for this website? Which problem are you trying to solve for them?

Comment: It looks like the Topic is the primary organization schema, while the Type and the Year are the metadata for narrowing the search results. Make sure how your users think/describe the materials when doing their tasks.

Comment: @AlexeyKolchenko It depends. Researchers would probably want to navigate by topic (regardless of year and type), but job recruiters may want to see all publications by year (regardless of topic)

Answer (score 1):

The type of search I think you are looking for is called a [faceted search](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/filters-vs-facets/), in that you may want to combine any number of the parameters (topic, date, author, type, etc).

There are a lot of sites that use faceted search - one example is the [Oxford Index](http://oxfordindex.oup.com/)